# XMLTable and GETXMLTYPE - How to convert XML to rows?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the following XML:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
    <record_id>2</record_id>
    <catalog>Y</catalog>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

How do I get everything inside "ROW" as a row with name/value?

This is what I have so far:

```
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.getxmltype ('SELECT record_id, catalog FROM courses WHERE record_id = 1') AS xml_data
    FROM dual
)
SELECT w2.col_name, w2.col_value, a.xml_Data
FROM a, XMLTABLE('ROWSET/ROW/*' PASSING a.xml_data
                COLUMNS col_name PATH 'name',
                col_value PATH 'text()') w2
```

Basically I want:

```
col_name, col_value
record_id    2
catalog      Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle XMLDB has powerfull support for [XQuery and XQuery flower(FLWOR)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5092). Try this approach

```
with params as (
  select 
    xmltype('
      <ROWSET>
       <ROW>
          <record_id>2</record_id>
          <catalog>Y</catalog>
        </ROW>
      </ROWSET>
    ') p_xml
  from dual  
)    
select
  col_name, col_val
from
  XMLTable(
    '              
      for $i in $doc//descendant-or-self::*
        return <element>
                 <element_path> {$i/string-join(self::*/name(.), ''/'')} </element_path>
                 <element_content> {$i/text()}</element_content>
               </element> 
    '
    passing (select p_xml from params) as "doc"
    columns 
      col_name   varchar2(4000) path '//element_path',
      col_val   varchar2(4000) path '//element_content'
  )
where col_val is not null
```